# "Workspace.RedPedastal.Script:17: attempt to index function with 'Transparency'" on Roblox script

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a roblox script that will teleport the player and make a "Beam" animation, but when i activate the script by walking on the tele pad, i get this error

```
Workspace.RedPedastal.Script:17: attempt to index function with 'Transparency'
```

Code:

```
local Teleport = "BeachHill"
local Beam = workspace.Beam

function Beam() #Just here incase of need
    for i = 0, 100, 1 do
        Beam.Transparency = 1 - i/100
        Beam.Size = Vector3.new(2048, 1.8 + i/10, 1.8 + i/10)
        print(Beam.Transparency, Beam.Size)
    end
end
    
function Touch (hit)
    if script.Parent.Locked == false and script.Parent.Parent : FindFirstChild(Teleport).Locked == false then script.Parent.Locked = true script.Parent.Parent:FindFirstChild(Teleport).Locked=true
        local Pos = script.Parent.Parent:FindFirstChild(Teleport)
        hit.parent:moveTo(Pos.Position)
        for i = 0, 100, 1 do
            Beam.Transparency = Beam.Transparency - 0.01 #<- Error
            Beam.Size = Vector3.new(2048, 1.8 + i/10, 1.8 + i/10)
            print(Beam.Transparency, Beam.Size)
        end     
        wait(1)
        script.Parent.Locked = false
        script.Parent.Parent:FindFirstChild(Teleport).Locked = false
        end
           end
    script.Parent.Touched:connect(Touch)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions and variables in Lua live in the same namespace, so you can't have a function and a variable both called `Beam` in the same place.